# Why was a question about MDX syntax migrated to Database Administrators?

Tags: discussion, migration

There are lots of MDX questions on Stack Overflow, but this one [NULL values on MDX query (Total Column has Values)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/17896/2848) was migrated to Database Administrators, which doesn't even have a tag for MDX.

Why was this migrated?

Comment: Is it on topic on DBA.SE? If yes, what's the problem?

Comment: The DBA.SE FAQ says that it covers "Advanced Querying", but for basic SQL, ask on Stackoverflow. The question I'm asking about is basic MDX, which isn't explicitly covered by either FAQ, but in the spirit of how other questions are categorized, seems a much better fit on SO. The confusing part to me is the randomness of the migration. If a basic MDX question is migrated, why aren't all MDX questions?

Comment: Hmm... Whether MDX is explicitly on topic at DBA sounds like a very good question for Meta DBA. That said there are gray areas between the two sites, and even more so between SO and, let's say, Programmers. The primary motivation when migrating a question is for it to get better answers, that's not an exact science and it doesn't always work as expected. However since a moderator migrated this specific question, I'll go out on a limb and say he probably checked with the DBA mods before sending it over, and they confirmed that it would be better served there.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for explaining how it works. Cheers.